# How to update XML File using Linq to XML?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Section xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="Information Section">
  <ID></ID>
  <alternateID />
  <familyName></familyName>
  <givenName></givenName>
  <birthDate></birthDate>
  <age></age>
  <height />
  <weight />
  <sex></sex>
  <Address>
    <street1 />
    <street2 />
    <city />
    <state />
    <zipCode />
    <country />
  </Address>
</Section>
```

I have this empty xml template. I am wondering to how to update / insert value in the elements of this xml using LInq?

Thats what I am trying... needs direction...

```
 var Doc = XDocument.Load("Info.xml");
    var items = from i in Doc.Descendants("Section")
                select new
                {
                  ID = p.Element("ID").Value
                }
    foreach (var item in items)
          item.id = "VALUE"
??????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently creating a list of anonymous type objects with

```
 from i in Doc.Descendants("Section")
 select new { ... }
```

Instead, create a list of elements to update:

```
var items = from i in Doc.Descendants("Section")
     select i;

foreach (var item in items)
{
   item.Element("ID").Value = "VALUE";
   item.Element("Foo").Value = "Foo";
}
Doc.Save(...);
```

Note that XML is case-sensitive.

Comment: It there any option like Doc.SaveAs.. I don't want to save content in the original template.

Comment: Yeah, just use a different filename. There is no `SaveUnderOldFilename()` since the previous name is not stored.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. but one doubt..do i have to query again for Element Street1? Street1 element is under Address Element. For Example. form i in Doc.Descendants("Address") or some other way? See the above XML File

Comment: Just something like `item.Element("Address").Element("Street1").Value`.